# mongoDB, mongoose - aggregation an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections to aggregate.

1st is **colors** collection

```
{
    {
        _id: 1,   <- mongoose objectId
        name: red
    },
    {
        _id: 2,   <- mongoose objectId
        name: green
    }
}
```

2nd is **products**

```
{
    {
        _id: Id777, <- mongoose objectId
        productName: test prod 777
    },
    {
        _id: Id888, <- mongoose objectId
        productName: test prod 888
    }
}
```

and 3rd it **move** collection

```
{
    ....other fields here
    items: [
        {
            _id: an mongoose id,
            itemId: Id777 <- in products collection,
            itemColor: 1 <- id in colors collection,
            coutn: 7,
            ....other fields
        },
        {
            _id: an mongoose id,
            itemId: Id888 <- in products collection,
            itemColor: 2 <- id in colors collection
            cout: 10
            ....other fields
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to have an output like this:

```
{
    ////information from collection
    items: [
        {
            itemId: test prod 777, itemColor: red, count: 7
        },
        {
            itemId: test prod 888, itemColor: green, count: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
      const moves = await ProductMoves.aggregate([
            { $match: query }, // this is my query

            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'products',
                    localField: 'items.itemId',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'productName'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: { path: "$productName" , preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
            },

            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'colors',
                    localField: 'items.itemColor',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'cName'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: { path: "$cName" , preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
            },

            {
                $addFields: {
                    mItems: {
                        prName: "$productName.productName",
                        prColor: "$cName.colorName"
                    },
                    productName: 0,
                    cName: 0
                }
            }

        ])
            .sort({addedDate: -1})
            .skip(+req.query.offset)
            .limit(+req.query.limit)
```

but it returns only 1 element from the object array. probably I need something like a for loop, but i couldn't do it.

thank you for your responses, and have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `items` array
- `$lookup` with `products` collection
- `$lookup` with `colors` collection
- `$addFields`, `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from lookup result
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `items` array and pass other fields as well
- there is no external methods in an aggregate function, you have to use stages for sort, skip and limit like below
- `$sort` by `addedDate` in descending order
- `$skip` and `$limit` result

```
const moves = await ProductMoves.aggregate([
  { $match: query }, // this is my query
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "items.itemId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemId"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colors",
      localField: "items.itemColor",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemColor"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "items.itemId": { $arrayElemAt: ["$itemId.productName", 0] },
      "items.itemColor": { $arrayElemAt: ["$itemColor.name", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      items: { $push: "$items" },
      addedDate: { $first: "$addedDate" }
      // add other fields that you want in result like "addedDate"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { addedDate: -1 } },
  { $skip: +req.query.offset },
  { $limit: +req.query.limit }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FOulsFwNQHa)